hibernate flush mode configuration
using spring 3.2.1,
I found that the default flushModeType = Auto causing me issues as im trying to work on the object before persist it.
I tried to set the flushMode to COMMIT, but whenever it happens outside of a @Transactional method, it goes back to AUTO.
I tried set the flushMode as env var, and directly on the entityManager but gets the same behavior. whenever set the flushMode outside of transaction, it has no meaning.
entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
System.out.println(entityManager.getFlushMode());


prints 'AUTO'
updated:
the code been affected out of the auto flushmode:
private void insertImageToDB(String imagePath, Map<String, ImageMetaData> imageNameToMetaData, int numOfImages,
      int currentImage) {
    try {
      ImageDB imageDB = new ImageDB();
      imageDB.setGcsFullPath(imagePath);
      imageDB.setStatus(PENDING);

      setImageMetaData(imagePath, imageNameToMetaData, imageDB); //calling more setters in this method

      imagesRepository.save(imageDB); //this clause causing extra persistence. i can solve it locally by removing this, but preffer to work with explicitly 'save()' action in order to under where and when im doing the commit. 
      logger.debug("processed {}/{} images", currentImage, numOfImages);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("failed to save image {}", imagePath, e);
    }
  }


Solving it by setting the flush mode to something else is generally not the solution.

"causing me issues as im trying to work on the object before persist it." ... that's how JPA works. To allow you to do that. Don't ask about the solution you picked, ask about the problem you have.

OK, so what do you think? Gimby M. Denuim
in my method:

create an instance of the entity object
call several setters according to some logic.

what i saw was multiple tries to persist the the entity, and failure on unique constraint, as the record was already saved.
I found that in flushmode = commit i will get the persist action only once: when calling repository.save(obj)

You are probably doing the updating of the model wrong. But that can't be verified without any code. There is an edit link under the question, it should be used.
